# how to track TFS Check In made by a specific user

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

Is there any way to find out all the check In's Made by a user using TFS for a period of time ..I see all the pending changes but not the Check In's instead of going in to each web page and checking the view history ...

Comment: I use [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) for this. Much more versatile than just the regular history.

Comment: @MajorSanches TF Sidekicks is a good tool if you work somewhere that allows installation of 3rd party software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways without 3rd party add-ons:

1. Install the [Team Foundation Server Power Tools for TFS 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15836).  Then under Team Explorer, expand Team Members.  Right-click on the user and click Show Checkin History.
2. From the Visual Studio command line, you can also use the `tf history` command and do it for any source path as well.  Here's an example that shows commits in a date range recursively for the root source path:

   ```
   tf history "$/" /version:D"7/30/2012"~D"8/2/2012" /recursive /user:[USERID] /noprompt
   ```

   Add the `/format:detailed` option to that command it will give you file level changes for each commit as well.  Remove the `/noprompt` if you want a GUI window to appear where you can right-click on each changeset to view the details.

Comment: I am not able to see any team members option in the team explorer and I am not able to execute the above script on the command line ..Please advise

Comment: You need to run it from the Visual Studio command prompt.  I'll update my answer.